# PFX-P12 certificate import is not working on Linux Firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, https, ssl-certificate, certificate

I'm trying to import a self-made .PFX/.P12 to browser and I installed the .PEM on a device, created with XCA and being imported to firefox and Edge on Linux.

I'm only experiencing this problem on Linux. Same .PFX/.P12 is working fine on Windows 10 with Edge, Chrome and Firefox.

I've tried to import it directly on Firefox and Edge to "Privacy & Security < Certificates", import to "Your Certificates", it appears there but it's not working.
I installed XCA on Windows for importing the .P12 on Linux, and not working.
I installed XCA on Linux for importing the .P12, and not working.

I'm thinking about if this could be a permission problem on Linux machine

Comment: It's possible that the issue you're encountering is related to file permissions on your Linux machine. You should make sure that the .pfx/.p12 file has the correct permissions for the browser to read and use it. You can check the file's permissions using the ls -l command in the terminal, and adjust them using the chmod command if necessary.

Comment: I changed file permission to 777 but same issue.
I think it has to be a Linux problem... and I cannot reinstall the OS

Comment: How old is the Linux system and Firefox/it's used libraries. May be the P12 file uses the latest AES encryption algorithm and the used Firefox version does not yet support it, thus importing fails?

Comment: uname -r -> Linux debian 4.19.0-22-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.260-1 (2022-09-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux. Firefox 102.7.0.esr (64 bit). I installed Microsoft Edge but same issue.